# How do I select a row's cells and get their value through JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am working on the hotel reservation system and I want to select a cell from a table.

Given this table:

```
 Today 2/Jan/2012

 Date       2/jan 3/jan 4/jan 5/jan 6/jan 
 room 200   ||||||||||||||||
 room 201
```

Room no 200 is booked for 3 days, so no one can select this cell. But the other cell can be selected, i.e. anyone can reserve room 200 on 5 jan and 6 jan.

I want to create a solution with JavaScript or any other ASP control. How can I do this?

Comment: don't do it with javascript is my suggestion..

Comment: You may want to show us what you have(maybe an image of the grid). It is difficult to understand what are columns and what are rows,

Comment: @dotNETbeginner then please suggest me how i can do this.

Comment: @RahulKumar: do postback(or AJAX request) on every selection and mark that cell as unselectable from the server side..do validation at server end before confirming any room..

Comment: didn't get the solution yet....some guys saying purchase the room reservation control.. like daypilot control... Right Now i remove this feature.. guys if you can help then see the demo of daypilot rooom reservation system control i want same like this...but no idea how i can do this..

Answer (score 0):

When you build your table\grid from server add a read-only class for the cells which shows reserved days.

On client side bind\live a focus event for td's and in that event verify if that cell has read-only class if yes just cancel the execution and if not add a class to that cell to show selected behavior then store the selected cells information in appropriate place.